# MIPS DataPath, sllv signal after ALU

Tags: mips

Consider the following datapath for a single-cycle 32-bit MIPS processor.

[image: ALU]

Suppose the following code have been executed

```
ori $t7,$zero,3
addi $t0,$zero,0xF
sllv $t2, $t0 ,$t7
```

and that the processor is currently executing the sllv instruction.

What are the
signal value for C in hexadecimal number?

The solution that I have got is that the instruction sllv is a R-type and therefor the Alusrc = 0 and it is RD2 that goes to the ALU. The result is the rt - field which is $t0 and the code says it is 0xF.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

> The solution that i have got is that the instruction sllv is a R-type and therefor the Alusrc = 0 and it is RD2 that goes to the ALU.

Those statements are correct.

> The result is the rt - field which is $t0 and the code says it is 0xF.

That is also true, the RD2 datapath with the value in `$t2` goes to the ALU.

> What are the signal value for C in hexadecimal number?

The datapath labeled "C" is post ALU — it is the ALU output, so the value that will be written to `$t2`.  To answer this, you need to compute the value of the ALU for an `sllv` given the two known inputs.

Comment: Okey, Thanks! So $t2 = 0x78 and that is the result

Comment: Yes, that's the datapath labeled "C".